# query works in mysql workbench but not php and not sure why

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-workbench

$db works as it should, that is not the problem.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried echoing the query and that didn't throw an error. The file was UTF8 so I made that change.  I commented out the if statement because it was preventing the error from firing.  Once that was done the resultant error I am now getting is "Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\goals..." which tells me there is a problem with the query, but I don't see what that is.  I have run this precise query in mysql console and it works fine.

Here is the code as it stands:

```
$query3 = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Jim/Downloads/ActualSales.csv'
    INTO TABLE dailyActual
    CHARACTER SET UTF8
    IGNORE 1 LINES 
    (`year`,`month`,`division`,`account_nbr`,`Cust_Name`,`lastrep`,`Cust_Type`,`Ad_Type`,`amount`)";
    //echo $query3; 
    //if ($stmt3 = $db->prepare($query3)) {
    $stmt3 = $db->prepare($query3);    
    $stmt3->execute();
    $stmt3->close();
    //}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Jim

Comment: Check for errors. I think `\r\n` could be causing issues because that is going to be interpreted (because you are in double quotes).

Comment: how about some error checking: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Yup had error checking "Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt" doesn't provide me with much insight.  What would be the alternative to \r\n when in quotes?

Comment: @Dagon why a link to PDO?

Comment: @YourCommonSense stupidity ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run certain queries using prepared statements.

Besides, there is very little sense in running prepare() without any variable to bind.

Therefore, just change prepare/execute for the query() call.

To manage any other problem you may encounter, set up the proper error reporting, by adding this line before mysqli connect:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am a tad new at this, thanks for the patience and speaking in complete sentences for the newbee.  Now working great.